# Why changes made in Wagtail's Editor only appear with a delay in the backend (although can be seen in front tend)?

Tags: django, content-management-system, wagtail

For several months now, when I edit a Page in the Editor of Wagtail and click "Save", these changes sometimes (often at certain times) disappear from the Editor. I can see it because when I edit content, I immediately go check the result in frontend and go back to the Editor to edit mistakes for example. In those situations, I can see the right content in the front end, but not in the back end. I eventually discovered that I need to wait, and after a few minutes at most, the changes appear back in the Editor. Sometimes, if I make successive editions, some of them will appear first, and then the other.

Simple example: I add a picture to a blog post, and click Save or Publish. I can see the picture in the front end, but when I come back to edit this page in the back end, the picture is not there anymore. If I wait for a little (either come back or just wait and refresh the page in the Editor), the picture will (re)appear in the Editor.

Note that the CMS seems to really save the changes because I can see them in the front end and in the back end in some cases. For example, if I choose a Category for a specific page, I can see it in the front end on the page, and in the Page list in the CMS, but not in the Page Editor of the page itself (or not after waiting a few minutes).

Finally, the issue concerns a lot of changes: adding or changing a picture, adding or removing a content block, editing text, adding / editing a publishing date, ... so it seems rather general.

Of course, it is making working with Wagtail very inconvenient on a daily basis.

---

Our web agency installed a Varnish cache system last year, and the start of the problem I described could be in the same month but I cannot be sure. They checked and guarantee me that the cache does not affect the back end of our site.

I also tried the Slack channel for Wagtail support, but no one seemed to know this specific issue.

We recently upgraded to Wagtail 4.1 and the issue is still present.

I did not try to keep a journal of these issues but I can say that sometimes it does not happen at all, and some days or times the delay is quite long (several minutes).

Any idea? I am not a developer, so I want first to know if someone knows this issue and/or has any idea what it might relate to.

Comment: That is totally bizarre. I am having a hard time imagining a situation where the front end was more up to date than the backend. Is the frontend rendered via Django templates? or do you have a JS app + a "headless" Wagtail install? And what browser do you typically use? Does the behavior change if you use a different browser?

Comment: I am going to investigate these points with our web agency. I tested on Edge instead of Chrome but had the same problems... Today the content of the backend and the frontend oscillated back and forth between the old content and the new content, sometimes with different contens on the back- and front- ends. Even when I checked the backend with Chrome vs Edge at the same time, the content in the backend was not always the same (eg old in Edge and new in Chrome or vice versa).

Comment: Do you have any way to restart the server processes? The oscillating back and forth smells to me like a change in the template files that isn't being consistently picked up. Your problem description doesn't sound like that should be it but it sure sounds similar to what happens in dev if you have template caching on and then change a template.